# How to add ITALIC Calibri font to FPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to add a Calibri font that has the Italic style.
I have tried the following:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Calibri','I',10);
```

However, when I try to run it, I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Undefined font: calibri I in C:\xampp\inc\fpdf\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\inc\fpdf\fpdf.php(510): FPDF->Error('Undefined font:...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\PdfExport\bpa_generator.php(906): FPDF->SetFont('calibri', 'I', 10) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\inc\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 271
```

May I know how I can overcome this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Did you add/create a Calibri italic font file in your font directory?

Comment: I don't have it with me and I can't seem to find it online. Would you be so kind as to point me to where I can actually download it.

Comment: I don't know where you can find it but if you don't have it that explains your problem.

Comment: I have found out how. First download the font file, Since Calibri Italic is free there were plenty of websites that offered it. I downloaded mine from https://best-font.com/fonts/download-calibri-italic-font.html . After that I visited this page http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/ . Where I uploaded the font file, since I wasn't sure about the type Encoding: I left it as it is. After clicking on Send two files were generated. I copied both to my folder that has the fonts ...\xampp\inc\fpdf\font.